# why the chinese words is chaos in monotouch/ios7

Tags: unicode, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

ios7/xamarin studio 4.3/monotouch7.2:

it's just a simply static method return the human-readable message, but why the chinese words is chaos in monotouch/ios7 ( in debug-watch window & iphone UI)[image]

---

I have been attached the iPhone snapshot, 
and uploaded the project solution file, pls download it from:  http://pan.baidu.com/s/1o69G8xs

thanks for your help.

the source code is:

```
     public static string GetMsg()
    {
        //btw, this file was edited in microsoft visual studio 2013 
        //and shared to mac to compile&debug
        //(my business logic code is edit by vs2013)

        return "Please input mobileNo, chinese words is(but incorrect to display):" + "请输入手机号";  
    }


    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        string msg = TestLib.TestClass.GetMsg();
        UIAlertView alertDialog = new UIAlertView("", msg, null, "OK");
        alertDialog.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It turned out to be the source file encoding (ISO-8859) versus UTF8.

The hint was that copying the code to another file made this work as expected.

**ORIGINAL**

I'm not sure for the Xamarin Studio debugger (it could be a different issue) but this should work in your iPhone user interfaces.

Have you included the additional I18N assemblies (in the project options) ?

If so the please file a bug report (and attach a sample app) so we can look why the UI does not show up correctly in your application.

Comment: I have uploaded the source code at url: pan.baidu.com/s/1o69G8xs thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks. I found the source code file created in vs2013 is in GB2312/936, so in mac/xamarin it cannot work proberly. when I convert to UT8-8/65001, it work as expected.  But I advice xamarin team can improve it: xamarin studio can automatic convert it. Because my team member write logic code in vs2013, and others wirte the ui code and compile in mac (share code via SVN).

Comment: I have report to xamarin team. I will manually convert the source code file endcoding for the moment。（VS 2013=>File=>Advance save option=>Unicode ).